# Try-catch creates infinite loop

Tags: java, try-catch, infinite-loop

I need to be able to take user input until the input is greater than the initial price, but I also need to make it robust so that the user can't break the program by entering something other than a double/integer. If the user does enter something other than a double/int.

The problem is that it creates a loop and repeats "Please enter valid currency" + "Please enter: price"

```
 public static double findChange()
{
    System.out.println("\nPlease insert: " + price + " (enter payment amount)");
    initialPrice = price;
    while (payment < price)
    {  
        try{
            payment = kb.nextDouble();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter valid currency");
        }
        if (payment > 0){
            totalPayment += payment;
            price -= payment;
            price = (price * 100);
            payment = 0;
        }
        if (totalPayment < initialPrice)
            System.out.println("Please Insert:" + price);
    }

    change = totalPayment - initialPrice;
    change = Math.round(change * 100);
    change = change / 100;
    System.out.println("\nChange Given: $" + change);

    return change;
}
```

Comment: `price = (price * 100);` not sure what the reason is for this line... You basically set the price higher each time, likely meaning the user will never complete payment

Comment: You should only catch an Exception when you can handle that exception and just print it to the screen is like pretending it didn't happen, it is not handling or recovering from the situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you're seeing an infinite loop is that you never clear the invalid entry out of the input. If you look at [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29), it says

> **If the translation is successful**, the scanner advances past the input that matched.

When it fails, you should call `kb.next()` to remove the input that did not match a double, so that you can move on to the next user entry. Otherwise, you'll keep trying to parse the same invalid text over and over:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter valid currency");
    kb.next();
}
```

A few other things you can improve as well. There's no need to be using a `try` and `catch` here, since you can use the `hasNextDouble` method to check that the input is valid. If you do decide to stick with exception handling though, you should catch `InputMismatchException` rather than a generic `Exception`, or else you risk running into some more problems (for example, if the input gets exhausted). You can also put a `continue` in when the input fails, so that it doesn't evaluate the rest of the code which is assuming that you correctly read a value.

```
if(kb.hasNextDouble()){
    payment = kb.nextDouble();
} else{
    System.out.println("Please enter valid currency");
    kb.next();
    continue;
}
```

Note that there's still a problem with your logic, and the loop will never exit (since `payment` always gets reset to zero). I assume you want to do `totalPayment < price` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it to recognize any input, but only use doubles, try `Double.parseDouble(String)`. I also moved the rest of the logic to your try block, since it should only occur when valid input is received. If it can't parse the double, it breaks out without attempting the rest of the logic and tries again.

```
while (payment < price && price > 0){
    try{
        payment = Double.parseDouble(kb.next());
        if (payment > 0){
            totalPayment += payment;
            price -= payment;
            price = (price * 100); 
            payment = 0;
        }
        if (totalPayment < initialPrice){
            System.out.println("Please Insert:" + price);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter valid currency");
    }
}
```